# VMWare Player doesn't start with NAT

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to do [Kioptrix Level 1](https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/kioptrix-level-1-1,22/). With a bridged network connection the `eth0` interface fails to start with the following error: `Determining IP information for eth0.... Failed`.
I tried changing it to NAT but when I'm starting the VM it switches back to `ethernet0.connectionType = "bridged"`. If I change the `.vmx` to read-only I can't start the VM.

How could I start the VM so it's accessible by the host?

Information about the system:

```
$ vmware --version
VMware Workstation 15.5.6 build-16341506
$ uname -r
5.6.0-kali2-amd64
```

Edit: Delete following line. VMware should start without changing the network adapter now.

```
ethernet0.networkName = "Bridged"
```

Comment: I am in Kali V2020 here (not Kioptrix) in VMware Workstation Pro (not Player).  With the machine OFF, go to the machine Settings and make a new Network Adapter. Assign it as NAT and when complete remove any Bridged Adapters.

Comment: Yea that seems to work. But I just created a VirtualBox VM for now. VMware doesn't seem to be good supported on Linux.

Comment: VMware Pro supports Linux fine. If I post the above answer, will you find that helpful?

Comment: I only checked whether the second interface was still NAT after I started the VM. But I think this is an edge case related to the VM image and the VMware players version so I don't know whether you should post it as an answer. But you can of course post it if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in Kali V2020 here (not Kioptrix) in VMware Workstation Pro (not Player).

Try the following approach:  With the machine OFF, go to the machine Settings and make a new Network Adapter. Assign it as NAT and when complete remove any Bridged Adapters.

That will cleanup the adapter interfaces used by VMware.